# Will this work as a $\pi_{4n\pm 1}$ prime counting function?

Tags: probability-distributions, prime-numbers

I forgot where it was, but I remember someone saying that you need $\phi(4)$, which is **two**, of Dirichlet's $L$ functions to get a prime counting function for primes  of the form $4n\pm 1$ less than $x$.

During a quite minute today I thought the following might work as well:

$$
\int_0^x \delta\left(\sin\left(\pi\frac{n\pm 1}4\right)\right)\pi_0'(n)dn.
$$

If I take 
$$
\pi_0'(x) = \operatorname{R}'(x) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}'(x^{\rho})
$$
with $\displaystyle    \operatorname{R}'(x^k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \frac{x^{k/n-1}}{\log x}$ and $\rho$ running over **all** the zeros of $\zeta$ function.

So only **one** $L$ function seems to be involved? Who is wrong?

Comment: You are probably thinking at "There are $\phi(n)$ Dirichlet characters modulo $n$" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#Dirichlet_characters). Note that you didn't exhibit the Dirichlet character (or L-function) here (except if you think that it is $\zeta$...). Concerning the aspect of $\pi'(x)$ an animation is at [Matthew Watkins link](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/encoding1.htm) (bottom).

Comment: @Raymond I think it is $\zeta$, isn't it? Thanks for the animation...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni would you mind if I use that gif (and a ref to the page, of course) here: [Divergence of the Derivative of the Prime Counting Function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/290108/19341)

Comment: I made these gifs for Matthew in 2000 or 2001 so they are kind-of his property. Anyway you may link the gif file directly with the !\[xx\](link) syntax ![xx](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/picomp.gif) with the same visual (embedding) effect (except in a comment here :-)).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thx...

Comment: Could you just replace the final link by the one to Matthew's page (he is referencing me anyway...) Thanks.

Comment: Concerning your question here your integral defines the odd Dirichlet character modulo $4$ but you use the zeros of the principal Dirichlet character modulo $4$ so... Anyway your trick may work and is (more or less) equivalent to add the contributions of $\pi_0$ in the $(4k+1,4k+2)$ intervals while subtracting the contributions in $(4k-1,4k)$ (you should merely introduce new discontinuities at the junctions...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7327/discussion-between-draks-and-raymond-manzoni)